# I can't change my skin because there is no button that says custom skins

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Every time I go into Minecraft to change my skin there is no button to change my skin. How can I change my skin?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to options then at the top there is a button.
It should work because it works for me.